Calculated column in MS Lists not returning any output?
I'm trying to populate a simple Calculated Column in MS Lists to provide a Risk Assessment outcome.
I've tried this in Excel and it works fine, but whenever I save the Calculated Column in Lists / SharePoint it returns '0', regardless of the what the field values are.
Is my logic flawed? Keen to get thoughts.
Ultimately, the columns in the List are as follows:

Risk ID
Impact
Likelihood
Risk Weighting (calculation of Impact and Likelihood value)

The Formula is as follows:

=IF(AND(Impact=1,Likelihood=1),"1",IF(AND(Impact=1,Likelihood=2),"3",IF(AND(Impact=1,Likelihood=3),"5",IF(AND(Impact=2,Likelihood=1),"6",IF(AND(Impact=1,Likelihood=4),"7",IF(AND(Impact=2,Likelihood=2),"8",IF(AND(Impact=2,Likelihood=3),"10",IF(AND(Impact=3,Likelihood=1),"11",IF(AND(Impact=2,Likelihood=4),"12",IF(AND(Impact=3,Likelihood=2),"13",IF(AND(Impact=3,Likelihood=3),"15",IF(AND(Impact=4,Likelihood=1),"16",IF(AND(Impact=3,Likelihood=4),"17",IF(AND(Impact=4,Likelihood=2),"18",IF(AND(Impact=4,Likelihood=3),"20",IF(AND(Impact=4,Likelihood=4),"22","0"))))))))))))))))


Your formula works perfectly for me.
What are your column types? Your formula wants your Impact and Likelihood columns to be numbers, not text. If your columns are text columns, the solution is to either change them to number columns or change your calculated column formula so it's looking for text.
eg.

(Impact=1,Likelihood=2) changes to (Impact="1",Likelihood="2")



Thank you for the above, I knew I'd missed something obvious... good point I simply added speech marks into the formula to indicate looking for text rather than number and all fixed!
